# Creating a Timer class, what data type should I use to hold values? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, types, timer, milliseconds

I'm creating a simple timer class which returns me e.g. the current time in millis. On linux I'm using gettimeofday. I'm wondering what return type this function should have.  i.e.
`double getMillis()` or `uint64_t getMillis()` etc... I would say `uint64_t` can hold bigger values and therefore recommended, though while googling I see lots of different implementations.

Any advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: `uint64_t` can hold bigger values then `double`??? `double` might (or might not) lead to precision issues, but it can definately hold bigger values then `uint64_t`.

Comment: Grizzly if I recall correctly they are both 8bytes, but double is signed + real.

Comment: In C++11 we have the <chrono> header for this. You can do `auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();`. The returned type is `std::chrono::system_clock::rep`. No need for platform specific code.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [what every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). `double `has an precision of about 17 digits, but can encode values up to 10^300 or something like this (above that comes infinity of course)

Answer (score 2):

My recommended data type to hold absolute time stamps in milliseconds is int64_t, mainly because time_t is signed.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the unsigned integer type since the number of milliseconds is a count.  Makes adding and subtracting dependable without float as well.  Most implementations I have used has unsigned integer types.